# SPARQL Calculating the difference between two date

Tags: date, sparql

What is the function to calculate difference between two SPARQL xsd:dateTime ?

I have found a reference to datediff, but this is not working. Does such a built in function exist in SPARQL as it does with most other query languages?

Comment: Did you ask this question earlier as an anonymous user and then delete it?  I could have sworn I answered an almost identical question earlier today.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I did ask a question, but that was part of it and not exactly this question. The two questions are different and I didn't delete it.

Comment: Ok, just curious, because there was a question about subtraction of xsd:dates, and the fact that they produce a duration, and how to get the number of years instead. That's why I had the SPARQL code all ready to go. Just a strange coincidence, perhaps.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some SPARQL engines may support date arithmetic directly. For instance, as mention in [this answers.semanticweb.com question and answer](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/24017/jena-arq-date-diff), Jena supports date arithmetic, and you can subtract one date from another and get an xsd:Duration.  Other implementations may support a datediff function.  For instance, [this Virtuoso example](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksSPARQLArithmeticCollection#Sample%20listing%20of%20musicians%20that%20includes%20age%20at%20time%20of%20death) includes the use of bif:datediff.  However, these are extensions and not guaranteed to be present in any particular SPARQL implementation.

For a more portable, though possibly less efficient solution, you can use the [year](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-year) to extract the year parts from a datetime.  This lets you do, for instance,

```
select ?age where { 
  bind( "1799-12-14"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> as ?death )
  bind( "1732-02-22"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> as ?birth )
  bind( year(?death)-year(?birth) as ?age )
}
```

and get results

```
-------
| age |
=======
| 67  |
-------
```

This has the potential to be off by one, depending on the months and days of the two dates, but you can similarly work around this by using the [month](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-month) and [day](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-day) functions.  [This thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/owlim-discussion@ontotext.com/msg01229.html) describes some of that sort of implementation.

Comment: @KimA.Jakobsen There a number of links, but I assume you mean the first one.  The answers.semanticweb.com site is a bit flaky at times.  I expect that it will be back up before too long.  That said, the internet archive /wayback machine has a copy at https://web.archive.org/web/20131026044936/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/24017/jena-arq-date-diff.

Comment: Ok, might have been a bit to fast, I home the site will get back up again soon. thanks for the archive page :)

Answer (score 9):

I found this post when I was searching on how to calculate an age in SPARQL. Thanks to Joshua Taylor for giving the correct hint. However I improved the code segment by adding an adjustment so it is not off by one year if the person hasn't had their birthday in the year of their death. I thought it might be useful to some, who find this post when searching for the topic, as I did.:

```
select ?age where { 
  bind( "1799-12-14"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> as ?death )
  bind( "1732-02-22"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date> as ?birth )
  bind( year(?death) - year(?birth) - if(month(?death)<month(?birth) || (month(?death)=month(?birth) && day(?death)<day(?birth)),1,0) as ?age )
}
```

Comment: Incredibly useful! Thanks for updating.